# Add existing typemap to new mapping engine

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm creating a new mapping engine for a custom mapping strategy to pass into `.ProjectUsing()`.

The problem is that when I create the new engine, it doesn't include all the mapping that was already created system wide.  It's a clean slate.

This particular object has nested object that also need to be mapped, so I'm having to duplicate the mapping profiles for several objects.  Is there a way to add an existing typemap from mapper to the new configuration?

This is how I'm creating the new engine:

```
private IMappingEngine SetupMappingEngine()
{
    var store = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);

    RegisterMappings(store);

    return new MappingEngine(store);
}
```

Inside of `RegisterMappings` is where I add the custom mapping, as well as all the duplicate mapping.

Is there a way to create the store to already include all existing mapping, or is there a way to add specific existing mappings to the store?

I can pull the existing type map easily

`var typeMap = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<Object1, Object2>();`

But I can't find a way to add that type map to the ConfigurationStore.

Comment: Why do you need a custom mapping strategy for ProjectUsing?

Comment: Long story short, we need to inject an object that can't be injected during the initial automapper setup.  It's a matching that's specific to the logged in user.